# Go to a section in the array, then echo what is next

Tags: php, arrays

Here I have an array of just words. I'm trying to go to a section of the array and then echo the item that comes right after it. (Look for Dog then echo Cat)

It seems it's unable to compare items with the code I have here, and thus creates an endless loop. It works just fine if I replace $Current = 'Dog' to $Current = 2 as expected.

Basically is there any way to compare something to an array item without using a number?

```
<?php 
    $List = array('Lizard', 'Bull', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Soda', 'Tomato', 'Hand');
$Current = 'Dog';

while (key($List) !== $Current) next($List);
    echo next($List);
?>
```

Comment: Please correct your grammar in your first paragraph. It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Fixed it up, hopefully that makes it a little more clear what I'm aiming at.

Comment: Your keys are `0,1,2,3,4,5,6` - Ofcourse those are never equal to `'Dog'`. Try `current($List)` instead of `key($List)` or use a for loop to find the index of current, add 1 (modulo the number of elements in the array to loop around) and use that as the index. You still need some special handling for the last element anyways. [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) might be worth a look aswell.

Comment: The key refers to the index of each array element, not what's in that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because `key()` returns the key of the current element (`$List`).

<s>What you want to do is harness [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to find the key (*2 in this case*) for `$Current` and compare it:</s>

```
while (key($List) !== array_search($Current, $List)) next($List);
    echo next($List);
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ECABHVFS0)

Returns:

```
Cat
```

---

And if that doesn't float your boat, simply change `key()` to `current()` to compare the string value instead of the numeric key value.

Don't compare the index of the array. As stated above, compare the current value:

```
while (current($List) !== array_search($Current, $List)) next($List);
    echo next($List);
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#zsHCJhomb)

Comment: Why would you use `array_search` inside a loop this way? It already returns the correct index (or NULL) - no need to iterate to it.

Comment: Forgot it was a loop @ccKep haha! Too early for me atm. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Cannot even begin to explain how embarrassed I am to have mistaken key and current!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
for($i=0; $i < ($c = sizeof($list)), $i++){
  if($list[$i] == $current){
    if($i+1 > $c){
      echo 'out of bounds';
      echo $list[0];
    } else {
      echo $list[$i + 1];
    }
  }
}
```

While it is a longer code, I find it to be more flexible and more reliable because the current array pointer location is invisible to the eye.

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop change the key() to current():

```
while (current($List) !== $Current) next($List);
    echo next($List);
```

If you don't explicitly specify keys when initializing an array, it is assumed to be numeric value staring from 0 (as in usual array offsets).

So by using the key() function, it was comparing the numeric offset with the desired value in $Current.  The current() function returns the actual value pointed to by the numeric key.  Refer to the manual for more details.

PHP arrays under-the-hood is a hybrid data-structure analogous to 'LinkedHashMap' in the Java world.